# How to create a "dynamic" column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm coding a portfolio analysis tool based off back-tests. In short, I want to add a column that starts at X value which will be the initial capital plus the result of the first trade, and have the rest of the values updated from the % change of each trade, but I haven't sorted out a way to put that logic into code. The following code is a simplified example.

```
profit <- c(10, 15, -5, -6, 20)
change <- profit / 1000
balance <- c(1010, 1025, 1020, 1014, 1036)

data <- data.frame(profit, change, balance)
```

So far, the only way I can think about is to create a separate vector that increases or decreases based off the change column, but I'm not sure how to do it in a way that it takes into account like the previous value, so doing `balance = start_capital * (1 + change)` which would give the proportional increase taking always into account the same initial value, not the previous value plus the change of the new one (I hope I explained myself).

Thanks,
Fernando.

EDIT

I have the correct change value on the actual program as each back-test updates the balance with the result of each new trade, so the change column on the real data is correct as it is properly updating, but my code combines several back-test and as the balance update is for each separate back-test and not the combined, it is not usable when combining everything, that's why I added the change column.

Comment: `1000 + cumsum(data$profit)` gives you `balance`, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, the trouble is that as it is a combined data frame of various data frames, I want to update the balance based off the change column, because when I combine 2 or 3 similar data frames, the profit column is proportional to the balance of that data frame, and that's why I wanted to go off the change column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this via `change` column we can use `Reduce`

```
start_capital <- 1000
Reduce(function(x, y) x + x*y, data$change, init = start_capital, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
#[1] 1010.000 1025.150 1020.024 1013.904 1034.182
```

`Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE` gives the output in a cumulative form taking the output of the current iteration as input to the next one.

Comment: That is just what I was looking for! Can you give me a brief explanation about what does the Reduce do? I kind of have a sense about it, but I don't think I'm fully understanding it

Comment: Updated with some description.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So each iteration is based of the updated value of X as stated on the first argument, the second would be the y value and the init argument takes place on the X value within the function on the iterations?

Comment: It starts with `init` value and `data$change[1]` these both are `x` and `y` in first iteration. So you get `(start_capital + start_capital * data$change[1])` as first output, output of this becomes new `x` and `data$change[2]` becomes new `y` and so on.

Comment: And I assume the first output is always the value passed to the init argument?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Hence I included `[-1]` here.