# How to apply Reduce() to groups based on columns of a Data Frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I posted some days ago this question: [How to create a "dynamic" column in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573482/how-to-create-a-dynamic-column-in-r#60573530) (reference so you can better understand what I'm asking on this one) to create a "dynamic" column, and the solution was to use the Reduce() function. Now, I'm looking to basically do the same (calculate the change in balance taking as reference the previous row) but with subsets of a data frame based filtered by a specific column. In short, what I want to do is to perform the same calculation but just for groups, so I have X value as the starting capital for group A, B and C, and the change in balance will "reset" to the starting capital for each group.

I know the explanation from above is not that clear, so here's a quick simplified version of what I'd like to achieve:

```
class <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")
profit <- c(10, 15, -5, -6, 20, 5)
change <- profit / 1000
balance <- c(1010, 1025, 1020, 1014, 1036, 1039)

data <- data.frame(class, profit, change, balance)

a <- data %>% filter(class == "a")
b <- data %>% filter(class == "b")
c <- data %>% filter(class == "c")
start_capital = 1000

a_bal <- Reduce(function(x, y) x + x*y, a$change, init = start_capital, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
a <- mutate(a, balance = a_bal, 
               profit = balance - (balance / (1 + change)))

b_bal <- Reduce(function(x, y) x + x*y, b$change, init = start_capital, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
b <- mutate(b, balance = b_bal, 
            profit = balance - (balance / (1 + change)))            

c_bal <- Reduce(function(x, y) x + x*y, c$change, init = start_capital, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
c <- mutate(c, balance = c_bal, 
            profit = balance - (balance / (1 + change)))

data <- bind_rows(a, b, c)

  class profit change balance
1     a  10.00  0.010 1010.00
2     a  15.15  0.015 1025.15
3     b  -5.00 -0.005  995.00
4     b  -5.97 -0.006  989.03
5     c  20.00  0.020 1020.00
6     c   5.10  0.005 1025.10
```

Obviously there's a more efficient way of doing this, but that's what I'm trying to find. My approach to solve it would be to create a function that takes as an input the data frame and the class where I want to apply the calculations, and output the data frame with modified values for that group, to then use some apply function to perform the operation on all the groups. But prior start creating that function, I'd rather to ask if there's a way to do this with an existing one. I was thinking on use group_by() along the pipe operator but as Reduce() is not from the tidyverse library, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it a group-by operation:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate(balance = accumulate(.f = ~ .x + .x * .y, change, .init = start_capital)[-1])

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   class [3]
  class profit change balance     y
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         10  0.01     1010 1010 
2 a         15  0.015    1025 1025.
3 b         -5 -0.005    1020  995 
4 b         -6 -0.006    1014  989.
5 c         20  0.02     1036 1020 
6 c          5  0.005    1039 1025.
```

Note that you misunderstand and are not limited to using just tidyverse functions with tidyverse.  You can use any suitable functions.  The function you have using `Reduce()` is fine, although for compactness I swapped it to `accumulate()` which is the tidyverse equivalent of `Reduce()` with the accumulate argument as TRUE.

```
data %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate(balance = Reduce(function(x, y) x + x * y, change, init = start_capital, accumulate = TRUE)[-1])
```

Or using `ave()` in base R:

```
ave(data$change, data$class, FUN = function(v) Reduce(function(x, y) x + x * y, v, init = start_capital, accumulate = TRUE)[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll replace Reduce to accumulate for the same reason! :) I have one question, if I don't set the init argument but pass just start_capital I wouldn't require to take away the first result of the accumulate function?

Comment: If you did that (where start_capital is a constant) then there would be nothing for the function to iterate over - you'd just get the constant back recycled to the appropriate length.  The initial value has to come from somewhere, either within your data, or passed additionally.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks a lot for your help! It worked out!